# Unique constraint - Key already exists in many to many

Tags: java, spring, duplicates, many-to-many

I have the classic many-to-many relationship between my users and their roles. 
It saves the first user correctly, but then when I try to insert the second user it gives me an unique key violation with `(role_id)=(56)` already exist...

I already tried many variations of fetching types. I am using Spring crud repositories.

**My user:**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")
)
private Set<Role> roles;

public void addRole(Role role) {
    if (roles == null) {
        this.roles = new HashSet<>();
    }
    this.roles.add(role);
    role.getUsers().add(this);
}

public void removeRole(Role role) {
    this.roles.remove(role);
    role.getUsers().remove(this);
}
```

**My roles:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<User> users;

public Role(Roles role) {
    this.role = role.getRole();
    this.users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**My database populating code:**

```
Role userRole = roleService.createIfNotExist(Roles.ROLE_USER);

//Role userRole = new Role(Roles.ROLE_USER);
user.addRole(userRole);

//roleRepository.save(userRole);
User result = userRepository.save(user);
```

If I create a new user role with new Role etc as shown in the commented out code everything works fine but I get duplicate roles saved to the data base.

Comment: where are you actually creating user? can you post the code?

Comment: User user = new User(
                signUpRequest.getName(),
                signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                signUpRequest.getPassword()
        );

Comment: Nothing special there

Comment: can you explain why is a many to many and not a one to many? (like the most common user->roles relation) ?

Comment: well one role can belong to many users like the USER_ROLE in my case and many users can have this role

Comment: can you post your user and role models?

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge instead of persist because if the entity exists it will update it otherwise insert it.

Comment: Did you set you cascade type as like @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})

Comment: Would I add this one both sides? I added it to the users side

Comment: You can add for user entity since you are persisting using "User"

Comment: Using merge in combination with persist seems to bring me a little bit closer. Now I get the following error: detached entity passed to persist: net.trincom.common.security.auth.entities.Role